# Cannot analyse opencv2 capture device frame by frame

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, image-recognition

I am piecing together a live facial recognition system on a webcam stream using python and opencv2. So far, I have managed to set up both the web cam stream and the facial recognition component, but I have had trouble putting them together.

Right now the issue is passing each frame from the webcam to the facial detection and recognition component.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    image=cv2.VideoCapture.grab(frame)
    image_grey=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image_grey,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(25,25),flags=0)
```

However, this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam_cv3(2).py", line 66, in <module>
    image=cv2.VideoCapture.grab(frame)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'grab'
```

I have been looking through the opencv2 documentatioon  and I can't seem to find any reason for `cv2.VideoCapture.grab` not being valid.

I am using python 2.7 with opencv2.
Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: [`cv2.VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) is a class. You first need to construct an object of this class, before you can call the member function.

Answer (score 0):

`ret, frame = video_capture.read()` already gives you `frame` as an np.array. You can then go on:

```
image_grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image_grey,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(25,25),flags=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but then we get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "webcam_cv3(2).py", line 66, in <module>
    image_grey = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
NameError: name 'image' is not defined`

Comment: It solves that problem, but then gives us: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam_cv3(2).py", line 83, in <module>
    Datafile["Data"]=Data_list
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 133, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key] = f.getvalue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 79, in closed
    raise ValueError('invalid operation on closed shelf')
ValueError: invalid operation on closed shelf`